# boolean condition check in Thymleaf is not working

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using Spring boot and Thymleaf in my application.I am sending a CommonResponse model from backend to view and in that model there is a property "isLoggedIn" which is a boolean
value and i am using that value to add a style like this

```
   <li class="nav-item hide-on-scroll" id="sign_in_menu" th:style="${commonResponse.isLoggedIn == false ? '' : 'display:none'} ">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Sign in</a>
   </li>
```

when i run this gives me a error

"Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "commonResponse.isLoggedIn == false ? '' : 'display:none'"

It happens when "isLoogedIn" property is part of this model "CommonResponse".but if i pass this as a standalone property it works fine

```
 <li class="nav-item hide-on-scroll" id="sign_in_menu" th:style="${isLoggedIn == false ? '' : 'display:none'} ">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Sign in</a>
 </li>
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When a property is part of the Java bean the properties are referred to by their property name. For example:

```
class MyBean {
  Boolean myBooleanProp;
  public Boolean getMyBooleanProp(){ return myBooleanProp; }
}
```

Then in Thymeleaf you access as `${myBean.myBooleanProp}`

Also when using Boolean props, it is sufficient to have `${myBean.myBooleanProp ? 'true' : 'false' }` or `${!myBean.myBooleanProp ? 'false' : 'true'}`

Answer (score 0):

try the following instead

```
 <li class="nav-item hide-on-scroll" id="sign_in_menu" th:style="${commonResponse.isLoggedIn} ? '' : 'display:none' ">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal">Sign in</a>
   </li>
```